# Clicking menu item with submenu opens all other sub menu's on mobile

Tags: wordpress, navigation

used below jquery function to add functionality to slide toggle the submenu of the menu items which has got children for the mobile viewport.

```
        $('.submenu-open').click(function(e) {
        $('.menu-item-has-children li').slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

But, it opens all the menu items with children at the same time (on mobile viewport), But it should only open the submenu of that menu item.

here is the [link](https://nrl-svi.grindstone.dev/)

Comment: If i check it, everything looks fine. What's the exact issue?

Comment: I see now. You are talking about the mobile viewport. That is a crucial detail to add.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the exact solution, it is more on the line of what you need.

Vanilla JS, without JQuery:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.submenu-open').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.target.querySelector('.menu-item-has-children li').classList.toggle('slow');
})
```

Your problem ist, that you aren't adding the class to only the clicked element, but all of them.

Comment: hi @frizzant, thank you for your insight. when i use this function i am getting an error in console that its not a valid function.

Answer (score 0):

Within the click event listener's callback function, you have to use jQuery's `$(this)` object to first off target the very `.menu-item-has-children` where the click event occurred.

Then use the method [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) on that object to target the related unordered list `.sub-menu`:

```
$('.submenu-open').click(function(e) {
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you @bitski, tried to use this before posting and didn't work